# Beginner C Program - How do I return necessary output from loop in anagram program?

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

Thanks for viewing my question!

I am trying to practice creating a working program from a textbook sample exercise in C (I'm still a beginner and I'm learning through books/notes) that will determine whether two strings entered by the user are anagrams (regardless of case or spacing).
Why is my program compiling, but not getting past the first getString prompt in order to allow the user to input the second string?
Here are the goals of the exercise, and what code I have written so far (at the bottom).

**Algorithm**
Read the first string, then write a loop that uses an array of 26 ints to count how many
times each letter has been seen.
Read the second string, this time decrement each letter’s count in the int array.
The strings are anagrams if every single element in the int array is 0.
Ignore any characters that aren’t letters. Treat upper-case letters as the same as their
lower-case equivalent. Help on this is given below.

**Functions required**
You are required to use the following functions. You must design appropriate parameters
and return types. You may also add other functions, if they make your program simpler
and clearer.

**main()**
Declares variables, then calls the functions described below to solve the problem.

**initialize()**
Clears the contents of all of your char and int arrays before you read the first string.
(Set every element in the char arrays to the null character ‘\0‘.)

**getString()**
Prompts for and reads a string from input.
Call the standard library function gets() from  as you do this. Function
prototype is: char *gets(char s[]); reads the next input line into the string s; it replaces the terminating newline with ‘\0’.
It returns s, or NULL if end of file or error occurs.

**setLetters()**
Loops over every character in the first string,
and updates the count for that letter in the int array.
Call the following standard library functions from
 as you do this. Function prototypes are:

**int isalpha(char c)**
returns non-zero (true) if character c is a lower- or upper-case letter

**char tolower(char c)** 
if character
c is an upper-case letter, returns the corresponding lower-case letter; otherwise it returns c

**checkLetters()**
Loops over every character in the second string, and subtracts 1 from the count for that letter in the int array. Very similar to setLetters().

**isZero()**
Loops over the int array. Returns TRUE if every element is 0, FALSE otherwise.

**This is the code I've written so far, it compiles but doesn't get to the second string:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define ABC 26


/* lab5.c: Compares user input to determine if they are anagrams */
char initialize(char s1[], char s2[], int count[]);
char getString(char s[]);
char *gets(char s[]);
int setLetters(char s1[], int count[]);
int checkLetters(char s2[], int count[]);
int isZero(int count[]);

int main() {

    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];
    int count1[ABC] = {0};

    initialize(string1, string2, count1);

    getString(string1);
    setLetters(string1, count1);
    getString(string2);
    checkLetters(string2, count1);

    isZero(count1);

}
char initialize(char s1[], char s2[], int count[]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        s1[i] = '\0';
        s2[i] = '\0';
        count[i] = 0;
    }
}
int setLetters(char s1[], int *count[]) {
    int i = 0;

    while (s1[i] != '\0') {
      if (isalpha(s1[i])) {
        count[tolower(s1[i]) - 'a']++;
        i++;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
int checkLetters(char s2[], int count[]) {
    int i;

    while (s2[i] != '\0') {
      if (isalpha(s2[i])) {
        count[tolower(s2[i]) - 'a']--;
        i++;
      }
   }
}
char getString(char s[]) {

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    gets(s);
}
int isZero(int count[]) {
    int i;
    int x = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ABC; i++) {
        if (count[i] != 0)
            x = 1;
    }
    if (x == 1) {
        printf("Not Anagram");
    }
    else {
        printf("Anagram");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the string: mattress
Enter the string: smartest
Not Anagram
```

...and that's not exactly the correct output. :P

Comment: Didn't this question get asked earlier today?

Comment: Several things are wrong with your code; it shouldn't even compile in first place. `setLetters` is declared to return `int` but it return a pointer to `int`. `initialize` declared to return a `char` (why???), but it doesn't return anything. `getString` has a different prototype than laid out in the assignment.

Comment: The loops inside `setLetters()` and `checkLetters()` need to increment `i` at the end of the loop body.  You'd get an infinite loop as it is now.

Comment: **NEVER, NEVER, NEVER USE `gets`** It is no longer part of the C standard due to severe security problems. Use `fgets`, `getline` or `scanf` instead. (`getline` provides a few niceties the others don't like returning the number of characters actually read, and allocating memory to hold your input if `lineptr` is set to `NULL`) However all will work fine. (this question was already answered several hours ago)

Comment: 1) `s1[i] != '\0'` at `initialize` : use uninitialize `s1`. 2) `while (s1[i] != '\0') {` at `setLetters` : it will be an infinite loop because `i` does not change.

Comment: Dmitri & @BLUEPIXY Thank you for spotting the infinite loops, that's exactly what was hindering my second getString call! Though, I still don't understand what you mean about the initialize function? :P

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for clarifying this, however this particular assignment is telling me to use it. I'll follow your advice in my own future projects! ^-^

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I've changed setLetters to take *count[], is that how I correctly return the value I need? :)

Comment: As a diagnostic: add a function that lets you print the value of the count1[] array. Then you can check the value between `setLetters()` and `checkLetters()`, and see for yourself what's happening.

Comment: About C pointers: `int count[]` and `int* count` are both pointer to int. But `int* count[]` is a pointer to an array of pointers to int -- not what you intended.

Comment: in `checkLetters()`, did you forget to initialize index i to 0?

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find [your solution in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57b9bfb9-b16b-4dd7-bf48-732e6a0c4504/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, I meant to post an example to replace your `getString` function last night. Below is a simple example of a function `fgetsinput` you can use to get input from `stdin` using `fgets` that will greatly improve security/vulnerability of your code. Note when using storage created statically on the stack, it is normal to `#define` a constant representing the largest line of input (or string) to be read. Below, the maximum string size to read is a constant `MAXS` defined as `256` initially. You can adjust as required. Normal range of values see are generally between `128` and `2048`

Also **note** by initializing your storage string to all zeros (null), you are filling the string with `null-terminating` characters insuring that your input will **always** be `null-terminated` unless you overwrite the last null at `MAXS-1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 256

char *fgetsinput (char *s)
{
    fgets (s, MAXS - 1, stdin);     /* read string from stdin   */

    size_t len = strlen (s);        /* calculate length         */

    if (s[len-1] == '\n')           /* if last char is newline  */
        s[len-1] = 0;               /* set to null-terminator   */

    return s;                       /* return adds flexibility  */
}

int main (void) {

    char line[MAXS] = {0};                  /* initialize to zero (null)    */

    while (strcmp (line, "quit") != 0)
    {
        printf ("\n enter a string : ");
        fgetsinput (line);                  /* return not used in this call */
        printf (" string in line : %s\n", line);
    }

    printf ("\n enter a string to assign to pointer  : ");

    char *p = fgetsinput (line);            /* return assinged to pointer   */
    printf (" What is the value pointed to by 'p'? : %s\n\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/getinputex

  enter a string : A string for fgets to read.
  string in line : A string for fgets to read.

  enter a string : quit
  string in line : quit

  enter a string to assign to pointer  : A string for fgets to read and assign.
  What is the value pointed to by 'p'? : A string for fgets to read and assign.
```

The function can easily be extended to read from any file stream by passing a file descriptor as one of the arguments to the function. (e.g. `char *fgetsinput (char *s, FILE *fp)`). You could then replace `stdin` in the function with `fp` and read from any open file stream.

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions David! I have updated my code to output the correct results according to the exercise instructions. :)

Comment: Good, there are a lot of smart folks here that are happy to help. As you go forward learning C, the key is simply to -- slow down. C is an 'exact' language. That is a great asset, and a requirement of any language that gives you such immense low-level control over hardware. Each part of each statement matters. Other languages may allow broad syntax that is 'close-enough'. With C, it's either 'correct' or 'wrong'. A little additional time learning C is time well spent.

Comment: Yes sometimes I feel very intimidated by how "exact" the language is, and how I feel like everything has to be calculated manually; I will follow your words of wisdom, thanks! Have a great week David! :)